# Solutions for top aligning different heights div in float left

Tags: html, css

Here is a jfiddle or the example : https://jsfiddle.net/mwL4L2a4/1/

```
.all {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:60%;
}

.division {
float: left;
vertical-align:top;

}

.full {width : 100%; border:1px solid black;}
.half {width: 48%; border:1px solid black; }
.third {width : 30%; border:1px solid black;}
```

I have different div that cover either full, half or third of the lenght of its parent. Using float left, all div tend to cover the parent width, but i wish to avoid having gaps between div lines. My div heights are changing and the width are specified by the class.

There is no regular pattern when appending divs. It can either be full, half, two-thirds, one-third. I usually would take in account the size of the previous div width when creating a new one, in order to fill the line completely (3*1/3), 2*1/2, 1/3+2/3.. etc)

I can eventually, add a certain class to a div if for example when its height is higher than the previous one; or add a new class if one div is placed before a two previous div, etc.. Is that the path i should look into to make it work, by writing a jquery for each possible case ?

Here is a visual example of the issue 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSqzu.jpg and
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xRwP.jpg

Ive read a few posts concerning this question on the forum, and it seems that neither display: table, table-cell seems to work as there is a altenated arrangement of the div width, and also a variable height. Also, masonry js can't apply as it takes a fixed width value for all divs. And when using salvatore you cannot alternate between div widths as every colum has to contain one element per line.

I thank you for help, and hope not being redundant.

Comment: Usually this is done with a javascript library for fitting pieces together - the term to search for is 'masonry' and ones I have used to not require fixed widths: I have used them with responsive columns - there are a lot to choose from. CSS floats go "under" the last, so they don't fill gaps. An alternative is to set minimum heights per row, maybe with flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Using Packery, i solved my problem.

http://packery.metafizzy.co/